# Replace all resources under specific url with Django REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

suppose I have a certain model:

```
class PricePeriod(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    arrival_date = models.DateField()
    departure_date = models.DateField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places=2)
```

The view:

```
class HousePricePeriodList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PricePeriodSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        return PricePeriod.objects.filter(house = self.kwargs['houseId'])
```

And the serializer:

```
class PricePeriodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

many = True

class Meta:
    model = PricePeriod
    fields = ('name',
              'arrival_date',
              'departure_date',
              'price')
```

This view lives under the url:

```
/houses/:houseId/price_periods
```

Editing these price periods individually will be very rare, they are created, updated and deleted a lot.

What I would like to achieve:

A PUT of an array of price periods to /houses/:houseId/price_periods would delete all price periods associated with that houseId, and replace them with the ones in the request body.

Is there a standard way to do that in DRF? Or do I have to write custom views/serializers?

Comment: You will have to write your own logic for this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

DRF documentation is very good. You have several options:

- http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-create
- https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk

Some notes:

- Your `PricePeriod` misses the `House` foreign key. I guess you forgot it
- Your `get_queryset` works but i invite you to check http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/. This is simpler

Comment: Thanks, I guess this was just a case of RTFM. I'll post my code once I'm done writing it.

Answer (score 1):

So, turns out it was pretty simple.  I have to agree with Guillaume that the DRF documentation is excellent and I should have read it.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

The urls:

```
url(r'houses/(?P<houseId>[0-9]+)/price_periods/$',
    views.HousePricePeriodList.as_view(),
    name='house-price-periods-list'),
```

The serializer is just a standard ModelSerializer:

```
class PricePeriodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PricePeriod
        fields = ('name',
                  'arrival_date',
                  'spearture_date',
                  'price')
```

Please note that the serializer does not include the house id, since that one it provided through the URL.

The model is pretty standard as well:

```
class PricePeriod(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    house = models.ForeignKey(House, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    arrival_date = models.DateField()
    departure_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places=2)
```

The only thing that was non-standard was the view, which is simply a class-based view based on APIView:

```
class HousePricePeriodList(APIView):

    def get(self, request, houseId):
        pricePeriods = PricePeriod.objects.filter(house = houseId).all()
        serializer = PricePeriodSerializer(pricePeriods,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, houseId):

        serializer = PricePeriodSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            oldPricePeriods = PricePeriod.objects.filter(house = houseId)
            oldPricePeriods.delete();

            # Add the house_id from the url to the objects
            for period in serializer.validated_data:
                period['house_id'] = houseId


            #write to db
            serializer.save()

            return Response(serializer.data)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The DRF tutorial actualy describes this very well. It starts out slowly, building up from standard Django stuff to the very high-level stuff. It's really worth a read, as only a quick glance may yield the impression that the framework is very high-level, while it actually allows you to go as low-level as you want.